# fectching textbox value from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am using angularjs, where i have created a login form and a controller where i am trying to fetch the values of textbox.
My html looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user.uname" placeholder="Enter username" ng-model="usname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Firstname:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user.Firstname" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
        </div>
```

and i have got the controller like:

```
module1.controller('RegisterController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.XHR_Result = "XHR Not Yet Initiated";

  //  $scope.User = {};

    $scope.User =
        {
            username: "",
            Firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            emailID: "",
            password: ""
        };...................
```

In the controller i would like to fetch the value of the textbox defined above in the html page.
Can you please let me know, how can i get the value of the textbox in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use the angular two-way binding

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

for your code all what you need to do is to assign the `ng-model` on the `<input>` element to the `user.Firstname`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.Firstname" id="user.Firstname" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
```

Comment: I heard that two-way binding is going away with the new version of Angular coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the awsome two-way binding in Angular, you don't have to do any extra work for this.

When you have it declared like this:

```
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    ...
    <input type="text" ng-model="username">
    ...
</div>
```

Now this value will automatically be available in the controller 'FormCtrl' as:

```
$scope.username
```

Comment: using $scope.username is giving the value as null.

Comment: Did you load the controller with ng-controller in your html?

Comment: I am not using ng-controller. I am using routes to define the controller

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set every string to "" for angular to work

First use

```
 $scope.User = {};
```

Then as html use

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user.uname" placeholder="Enter username" ng-model="User.UserName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="User.FirstName" class="form-control" id="user.FirstName" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
</div>
```

to test add

`{{User.UserName}}` in a div to see if it works

also i used CamelCase where needed so try it and let me know

Comment: i uncomment $scope.User = {}; and comment the other lines, but the value is coming as null

Comment: Does the code i edited work? also change username to UserName
and use propper camelcase in your code it makes it a lot more readable for others

Comment: no, that doesnt work. Might be i am doing something wrong. Can you please let me know after using $scope.User = {}, how will i get particular values like username, firstname?

Comment: $scope.User.UserName should give you that value

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$scope.username` in init function `FormCtrl` controller then your value will be available.